# Samba server on Red Hat - "client signing = mandatory" bug

Tags: linux, security, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux

My Samba version is 4.10.16 and I've got a problem with setting **client signing** variable to **mandatory**. It is properly set in /etc/samba/smb.conf, but testparm show **client signing = required**.
My RH version is 7.9.
Does anybody know how to solve this, if possible at all...

I've double checked if testparm is using proper config and it is correct.
This is what man page shows:

```
client signing (G)

           This controls whether the client is allowed or required to use SMB signing. Possible values are auto, mandatory and disabled.

           When set to auto or default, SMB signing is offered, but not enforced.

           When set to mandatory, SMB signing is required and if set to disabled, SMB signing is not offered either.

           IPC$ connections for DCERPC e.g. in winbindd, are handled by the client ipc signing option.

           Default: client signing = default
```

There's no **required** value and setting this variable to **auto** shows **client signing = if_required** in testparm.

I've also found similar problem in Samba's Bugzilla from 2015 with status NEW - [link](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11168). I assume this bug hasn't been resolved since then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The parser](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/blob/master/lib/param/param_table.c#L116-138) accepts a few undocumented aliases, but they're all the same value:

```c
/* SMB signing types. */
static const struct enum_list enum_smb_signing_vals[] = {
    {SMB_SIGNING_DEFAULT, "default"},

    {SMB_SIGNING_OFF, "No"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_OFF, "False"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_OFF, "0"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_OFF, "Off"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_OFF, "disabled"},

    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "if_required"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "Yes"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "True"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "1"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "On"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "enabled"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_IF_REQUIRED, "auto"},

    {SMB_SIGNING_DESIRED, "desired"},

    {SMB_SIGNING_REQUIRED, "required"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_REQUIRED, "mandatory"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_REQUIRED, "force"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_REQUIRED, "forced"},
    {SMB_SIGNING_REQUIRED, "enforced"},

    {-1, NULL}
};
```

When the value is converted back to a string by `testparm`, it uses whatever happens to be the first alias in this list.

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand what was written as reply in Bugzilla. Thank you for clarification!
It's kinda confusing anyway...